# how to install mpgtx from source code

Tags: vps, linux

i am new on linux server.
i have mpgtx folder in my root, how can i install it ?

in readme file it is written;

./configure && make

when i type this i get permission denied error ?

thanks

EDIT:

Here the steps i done

```
root@server [/]# cd /mpgtx
root@server [/mpgtx]# ./configure
-bash: ./configure: Permission denied
root@server [/mpgtx]# make

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Hello !
    I'm afraid I'm a dummy Makefile.

 My goal in life is to politely ask you to run the configure script to actual-
 ly generate a real Makefile.
 Would you be kind enough to type "./configure --help" to see the options that
 will suit your needs ?   Please note that typing "./configure" without option
 will generate a Makefile that will suit most people needs.

 I wish you a good day. Please don't drive to fast.
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

root@server [/mpgtx]# ./configure
-bash: ./configure: Permission denied
root@server [/mpgtx]#
```

Comment: try ./configure and make commands on their own. Then tell us which one is giving you the error. Also what is the error text?

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the directory you are working in, is writable by you. Did you untar the package as root and trying to configure/make/make install as a user?

Go up a level and issue the command ls -l that will list the permissions that you have on the directory you are working in.